# Novel about a microscopic civilization living inside the Sun

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space

I read a novel a few years ago about a tribe of alien people living inside the Sun. They were surfing the electromagnetic waves, visiting a floating city, and traveling towards the center of the Sun to learn of their origins. It was pretty far out, but still felt somewhat plausible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Read maybe five years ago. It felt like a story out of the seventees or eightees, but cant be sure.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is probably Stephen Baxter's *Flux*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_(novel)):

> Dura and her fellow human beings live inside a neutron star, as they have for generations. As long as they can remember, "glitches" (instabilities of the magnetic field inside the star caused by changes in the star's rotation) have happened from time to time. As the novel starts, the worst glitch that anyone can remember threatens to destroy her home. To survive, Dura must travel to a far-off city, and eventually outside of the star itself.
>
> ... the main race of the book, microscopic human-like beings who live within a neutron star, travel around using the magnetic field lines within that star.

Comment: This. The other possibility was _Dragon's Egg._

Comment: The title made me think of *Dragon's Egg*!  Fun story.  Now I'm going to have to check out *Flux*...